# AngularJS $http custom headers not working

Tags: angularjs, rest, header

I'm trying to add a custom header to an HTTP request but AngularJS does not seem to handle it. Here is my code:

```js
$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Schedule-service/login',
    headers: {
        'X-AUTHENTICATION': 'TRUE'
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    $cookies[constants.TOKEN] = response.hash;
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

I have tried to add this to the default headers but still nothing. What is wrong here?

Edit:
My request in the middle of doing GET:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Schedule-service/login
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-authentication
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/ScheduleWebClient/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
```

And after GET:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Schedule-service/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source

Request Headers:

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-authentication
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/ScheduleWebClient/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36

Response Headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with, sid,   mycustom, smuser
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 24 Jan 2014 20:33:23 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=5f4fc0d1318a2e63cd1ca9170386; Path=/Schedule-service; HttpOnly
X-AUTHENTICATION:*
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
```

Comment: try using the `headers` parameter sent to the success callback. (the parameters are `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`).

Comment: also, the HTTP header `X-` prefix [is now deprecated](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-xdash-05). why not use the standard `Authorization` header instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're performing CORS request and the request you pasted is preflight request. The application is working on port 80 but you're calling service on port 8080 hence its CORS cross origin. In the response above you see that the server will accept x-requested-with header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with.
```

The header should be visible in the next request